# How to convert slice to array

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm trying to create an array of Temperature and Time but my Time dimension is a slice. I am getting an error when I try to convert my slice to an array. 
"slice object is not callable"

```
filehandle = Dataset(path+indices,'r',format="NETCDF4")

timerange = slice(0, 1460)
temp = get_var(filehandle, 'tair')[timerange, lat, lon]

lat_file = str(lat_round)
lon_file = str(lon_round)
ncname = 'CRUNCEP_mstmip_Tair_'+year_url+'_lat('+lat_file+')_lon('+lon_file+').nc'
ncfile = Dataset(ncname,'w')


floats = [float(x) for x in timerange()]
data_out = temp*timerange
```

I want to make this an array, and create a Netcdf file. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you've used slice here in the first place, or why you're calling the result. Did you perhaps mean `range`?

```
timerange = range(0, 1460)
floats = [float(x) for x in timerange]
```

Comment: Range does work instead of slice, but now how can I convert this range to an array and create this file?

Comment: Er, what? Convert it to what, where?

Comment: so I'm reading in temperature data for a specific lat/lon from a huge datafile. I want to create a Netcdf that lists temperature in one column and time in the other. I've tried:
    data_out = temp*timerange
    data_out.shape = (temp, timerange)

and I get this error: " only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars "

any idea on how to fix this?